# OctoberCMS no Admin account found "Empty Backend Users"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, laravel-5, octobercms

Hi I am using October CMS, after installation when i try to login. I get "No User found", error.

After logging in to MySQL, doing `SELECT` for admin user, i get result :-

```
mysql> select * from backend_users;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I need help in re-generating admin account. How can i do it ?

Thanks

Comment: how you have installed OC ? from console or installer

Comment: Using October CMS installer

Comment: then how its deleted that record ?

Comment: in backend_user_group and backend_users_group there is record or not ?

Comment: While installing October CMS.  I got few error with blog posts table. I re-generated `php artisan plugin:refresh Rainlab.Blog` and installation was finished successfully. Now , when i log in to backend for first time. I get Invalid username and password. When i check mysql. It is empty like in question.

Comment: No record for `backend_users_group` and `backend_user_group`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73826/discussion-between-user3767643-and-anand-patel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is that you can delete all your tables from database(if you don't have critical data in tables) and fire following command from console

```
php artisan october:up
```

This command fire all migration(create table) and seed all datas.

Answer (score 0):

If is an issue with the migration and the user is not created you can manually seed the user with the following command

```
php artisan db:seed --class="\Backend\Database\Seeds\SeedSetupAdmin"
```

you will be able to access with admin admin